# ipad app minimum OS requirement mistake

Tags: ipad

I've recently submitted and had approved an iPad only app to the app store. My problem is that I acccidently left the Minimum OS requirements to 4.2. Doh!

Is there an easy way to change the OS requirement to 3.2 so that the original iPad can download and run it? e.g. through itunes connect. Or am I going to have to change the binary and resubmit as an update?

Be kind - this was my first attempt at submitting my first app to the app store.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to submit a new binary, as the minimum OS requirement is encoded in the info.plist of the application bundle.

Make sure you actually test on an 3.2 device first, though, as you may have inadvertently used a 4.2+ API.

Comment: Ok thanks. lol that'll teach me not to double check these things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to release an update to change that requirement. Note that when you change requirements you can never require a newer version, in other words, while it's OK to change it from 4.2 to 3.2, if later you decide to use a new feature from 4.2 you can't change the requirement back to 4.2.

Comment: Are you sure about not being able to up the minimum required OS version in an app update?  I've successfully updated apps that bumped the requirement from 2.2 to 3.0, then to 3.1.

Comment: @Daniel Dickison: Are you sure you changed the iOS deployment target and not the "Base SDK"? If you expand the requirements some customers would not be allowed to update.

Comment: Yup, definitely the deployment target. And yes, customers couldn't update until they updated their OS.  But 2.x to 3.x wasn't a big deal because all iOS devices support 3.x, so it at worse it's a small fee to upgrade (for iPod Touch users).  3.x to 4.x is not so simple because older devices are completely incompatible.